# Filter Array of Inner Arrays Based on Inner Array Length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

I need to filter out the empty arrays inside the array called **arr**.

Here's what I see when I `console.log([arr])`:

[image]

I have tried `console.log([arr].filter(arr => arr.length > 0))` with no luck (getting `[]`)

Comment: it appears `arr` is in fact an *object*, not an array. You've made an array by enclosing it in one (`[arr]` - an array of length 1 whose sole element is `arr`) but that's a bit strange and doesn't actually help.

Comment: arr is an object which has a few array properties. Do you want to delete the properties with 0 length?

Comment: And every other array inside the object is again enclosed inside another array so you need to get the values in your object (which are arrays) then get the length of the array inside that array

Comment: Try and do this `console.log(Object.values(arr).filter(i => i[0].length))`

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out by @robin-zigmond, you are dealing with an object here containing array properties.

You can use the `delete` operator to delete properties from an object:

```
for (let prop in arr) {
  if (arr[prop].length === 0) {
    delete arr[prop];
  }
}
```

This will remove all zero-length properties from the `arr` object.